# Getting TypeError in onFormSubmit trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used a Google Forms tutorial to tweak Form data to merge into a PDF and then send to an email.  I am getting the following error message when I try to run the script:

> > TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 11, file "Code")

I do not know how to fix the problem.  I have searched the web for an answer. Here is a copy of the script. I marked the 2 lines where the script is giving an error:

```
var docTemplate = "1ZSqmId2BBjtz6PmgQEmusjnkHGsFKD1CBSq0rrQk6Kc";  
var docName     = "TestCertificate";

// When Form Gets submitted

function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Get information from form and set our variables 

var email_address = "EMAIL@example.com";

//**(THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURRING ON THESE 2 LINES BELOW!)**

var full_name = e.values[2];
var Activity = e.values[3];

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id

var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
.getId();

// Open the temporary document

var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section

var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template 

copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', full_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyActivity', Activity);



// Save and close the temporary document

copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert document to PDF

var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 

// Attach PDF and send the email

var subject = "Report";
var body    = "Here is the form for " + full_name + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 

// Delete temp file

DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Here are links to the form and certificate I was testing.

- [Form/Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuZovKDjGH-idEVsLWVxR1piZTUxSUJJSmZyZEcxalE&usp=sharing)
- [Document Template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZSqmId2BBjtz6PmgQEmusjnkHGsFKD1CBSq0rrQk6Kc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: How are you "running the script"? If you're running it in the debugger, there is no parameter `e` being passed in - which is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I'm kindof a novice with more complicated script like this. It should pull from the form data spreadsheet the values. I'm not sure how to fix it.  I'm running the script in Scripts Editor in Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you're running a trigger function in the Script Editor. When you do this, the Event Parameter `e` is not defined - that's what the error message is saying.

For more background, see [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Here's a test function that will run your `onFormSubmit()` function multiple times, with the data that's already in your spreadsheet. It reads each row of the sheet, generates an object to simulate the Event you would get when a form was submitted, then calls the trigger function. If you place breakpoints inside `onFormSubmit()`, or rely on `Logger.log()`, this technique will allow you to test your trigger function.

```
function test_onFormSubmit() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange()
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  // Start at row 1, skipping headers in row 0
  for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row];
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
    e.namedValues = {};
    // Loop through headers to create namedValues object
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = e.values[col];
    }
    // Pass the simulated event to onFormSubmit
    onFormSubmit(e);
  }
}
```

I've done no other debugging of your original function... but this gets rid of that error message, so you can continue testing.

Answer (score -1):

I use the below code to test my triggers

```
//
//

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var resp = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1, e.range.rowStart,5 ).getValues();

/*
function test(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var respsht=ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var resp = respsht.getRange("A119:P119").getValues();
*/


//your code for doing something with the data goes here

}
```

I will comment out the onformsubmit portion and run the test portion.

Once the function is working, I will comment out the test function and activate the onformsubmit function.

Simple solution :)

Comment: You can't possibly have tested this code. It's missing a closing curly brace, and you've misspelled 'onFormSubmit'.

Comment: I use it all the time. I edited the answer.