# How to get onFormSubmit to trigger automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The "fix" (test_onformsubmit) code you gave, I have to manually run it every time there is new data in the spreadsheet. I was wanting it to automatically send the pdf to email when Form is submitted. Is there a way? Because the manual way runs the code exactly like its supposed to, but I want this as an automatic event so I don't have to do anything.

[See parent thread of original problem/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984230/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-when-trying-to-merge-google-form-data-to-pdf-and-send-to)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Read [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers). This function is an *Installable Trigger*, so you need to set it up to run when a form is submitted. It's easy - I would have thought a Forms tutorial would have walked through it.

In the Script Editor:

1. Choose Edit > Current project's triggers. You see a panel with the message *No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.*
2. Click the link.
3. Under *Run*, select the function you want executed by the trigger. (That's `onFormSubmit()`, in this case.)
4. Under *Events*, select *From Spreadsheet*.
5. From the next drop-down list, select *On form submit*.
6. Click *Save*.

From this point on, the function will be triggered whenever a form is submitted to the spreadsheet.

If you plan to share your script, each recipient will need to repeat these steps.

---

As an aside, you should change the email setting in your script, so it will work for ANYONE.

```
var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

Comment: I hate to be such a novice, but I really would like to get this to work so that I can share with my fellow educators. This way once they submit to the form it automatically creates a pdf of their response and sends the pdf as an attachment to their email address.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do we get the event e, that I can see in many tutorials and even in the documentation, from which we can get other parameters like "e.values", etc..? When I use onFormSubmit(e), it gave me error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined."
I also tried: "formSubmitReply(e)", which in turn is not working!

Comment: @Srichakradhar - you're asking a question in a comment on a 2 year old answer; would have been better to first search for an answer (which does exist), then ask a new question (if your search wasn't successful). Looks like you're running the function in the editor, where it's not receiving an event. See [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas).

Comment: It would be nice if it could use a function from any other script file too.