# how do I assign a unique ID into the form using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to pass a unique ID for each google form being submitted but I could not find anything so far.

I am thinking of using google web app script and make a simple input html first to enter unique ID and then a submit button where it redirects to the google form after submit button is clicked. The question is, where do I store that unique id? localStorage or Coockie, I tried this methods using coockies but I could not access that coockie from the OnSubmitForm event from script editor (apps script code). Is there any way that I can store a variable into the browser regarding the domain , so I can access it from any tab?

Comment: You would have to write a script in the receiving spreadsheet with a [trigger associated with the form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992718/how-to-get-onformsubmit-to-trigger-automatically).  OR use the timestamp, but if they are allowed to edit their submission  believe the timestamp will change

Comment: If you are using a Web App, you need to use `google.script.run.gs_ScriptFunctionName()` to send the HTML form data to the gs script.  [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  An "On Form Submit" trigger won't even run from a Web App form being submitted.  Unless you want to take input information from an HTML form, send that data to the server, then have the server submit a response to the Form?