# How to get filename when using google forms to upload a file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a google form which my users use to upload files.
**I record the following**

1. a unique id (input by user)
2. a category of the document (selected by the user via a dropdown in the form)
3. The file itself (uploaded by the user)
4. Google drive link that is recorded into the spreadsheet.

I am unable to find a way to get the actual filename, of the uploaded file.

**My requirement**

1. Extract the filename using the drive link as in 4 above using a custom function in the spreadsheet

OR

2. Any provision by which I can also record the filename of the uploaded file by way of the google form itself.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: changed title, corrected some spelling, made it a little less LOUD

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apps script triggered by `OnFormSubmit` or `OnChange` of the Google Sheets.

Here are some related post:
- [How to get onFormSubmit to trigger automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992883/5995040)
- [How to get form values in the submit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433069/5995040)

---

OR

Use an Apps Script Web App to host your form then control all the submitted details in Apps Script.

Here are some tutorials for this:

- [Upload Files to Google Drive with Google Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files)
- [How to Create Forms that allow File Uploads to Google Drive](https://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/)
- [Google Forms file upload complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22980821/5995040)

---

Based from my test (`OnFormSubmit()` and `OnChange()`), this can be complex as `OnFormSubmit()` will only get the fileID of the submitted item. You have to do another query to get the name of the uploaded file then save it to your Sheets. While in the Web App, you will be able to get the file name before uploading it thus lesser request needed for this implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rebot, I will have to learn web app then. thanks for your rply though