# Is there an addFileUpload method when creating a Google Form using Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm creating a Google Form with information in a Google Spreadsheet. The form being created has multiple file upload questions, is there a method to add a file upload question to the form using Google App Scripts?

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle('Do you have a cat or dog?')
    .setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
    .showOtherOption(true);

form.add????????????????()
.setTitle('Upload a photo of your cat');
```

Comment: "_Is there an addFileUpload method_" No. Form [item-types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type) don't include file upload, and [fileUpload](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload) was deprecated. You need to use the HTML service instead. Have you looked at [How to get filename when using google forms to upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46429686/1330560) - several source of content there.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that the item doesn't exist, it's too bad because I wanted to build a regular Google Form for a user using Google App Scripts