# Get content of Google Form response when submitting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google App Script to generate Google Doc that contains content of Google Form response (answer of question, uploaded image).
Is it possible to do the following?

- trigger Google App Script when an user submit a form (I think it is  possible by manually install trigger https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable )
- get the content of the form response
- generate a Google document that contains the content of the form response

## added the following after submitted

I want to know the answers of the following questions to implement this.

1. how to trigger App script when form is submitted
2. how to get form response object from triggered script

For the question 1, 
* We can manually install a trigger https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually
* We can get form response objects like this

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  Logger.log('form id = ' + form.getId() + ', length = ' + formResponses.length);
  const formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  const doc = DocumentApp.create('New response');
  const body = doc.getBody();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    const item = itemResponse.getItem();
    body.appendParagraph('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
        (i + 1).toString(),
        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
        itemResponse.getResponse());
  }

  docblob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  const file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
  DriveApp.addFile(file);

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    "mail address",
    "new response",
    file.getDownloadUrl())
}
```

Comment: It's definitely possible, do some research on [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Give writing the script a try then if you have any problems you can't solve, ask a question here. This is a little too broad at the moment because you don't have any code of your own to troubleshoot.

Comment: OK so you do not know the answer?

Comment: The answer to your question(s) is yes - it's possible to do this.

Comment: My question is 1. how to trigger app script, 2. how to get form content (or how to get form object when the script is triggered).

Comment: added questions

Comment: added a little bit. still do not know how to get the submitted response, not all of submitted responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Triggers:

First of all, you need to set up an `onFormSubmit` trigger.

Mogsdad has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992718/how-to-get-onformsubmit-to-trigger-automatically) for this:

1. Choose Edit > Current project's triggers. You see a panel with the message *No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.*
2. Click the link.
3. Under *Run*, select the function you want executed by the trigger. (That's `getResponse()`, in this case.)
4. Under *Events*, select *From Spreadsheet*.
5. From the next drop-down list, select *On form submit*.
6. Click *Save*.

**Note**: The trigger needs to be set up on the *spreadsheet* for this.

---

#### Get Response Values:

Once you have your trigger set up properly, all you need is:

```
function getResponse(e) {
  var response = e.values;
}
```

Here we're using event objects to get the values submitted in the form response. This returns the array of values being submitted to the spreadsheet, in the example I tested, the array looks like this:

> [25/07/2019 10:02:36, Option 1, Answer 2, Option 3]

---

#### References:

- [Setting up an `onFormSubmit` trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992718/how-to-get-onformsubmit-to-trigger-automatically)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)