# Event triggering when Google Forms add a row in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form with 3 questions.

Data collected are sent to a google sheet.

I have a function that performs auto sorting based on 1 column.

I execute this function inside onEdit and onChange functions.

However, when a new row comes in from the Form those functions won't get triggered and there's no sorting being made. I have to manually edit some cell to trigger it.

Is there an event that is being triggered when a new row comes in from the Form that I am unaware of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get onFormSubmit to trigger automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992718/how-to-get-onformsubmit-to-trigger-automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `onEdit` triggers only for edits made manually by humans,not for rows added programmatically by a background proccess.
- `onChange` behaves usually in the same way (there are few exceptions, such as edits triggered by `IMPORTRANGE`).

But see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers):

> An installable form submit trigger runs when a user responds to a
>   form. There are two versions of the form-submit trigger, one for
>   Google Forms itself and one for Sheets if the form submits to a
>   spreadsheet.

This is the trigger you need to implement. It is an installable trigger that you can bind to your function in the same way like the `onChange` trigger and it trigger on each form submit. It can be used in a script bound to either your form or your destination spreadsheet, whereby in your case the latter makes more sense.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I already tried having an onFormSubmit(e) function but I found out later about the installable triggers. I will accept the answer of course.