# Trigger bug when copying rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that copies rows from one sheet to another, which works when I run it manually:

```
function updateDataRange() {
  var formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastFormRow = formSheet.getLastRow();
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DataRange");
  dataSheet.clear();
  for(var rowCounter = 1; rowCounter <= lastFormRow; rowCounter++) {
    var sourceRange = formSheet.getRange('B'+rowCounter+':H'+rowCounter);
    var insertRow = dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var targetRange = dataSheet.getRange('A'+insertRow);
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
  }
}
```

However, when I run this via a trigger (e.g. `function onEdit(e) { updateDateRange(); }` ), there are gaps in the rows and some of the values will be left out. In this case, I know there is a "fix" by using `rowCounter` instead of `insertRow` to write the files instead of using `getLastRow()`, but one can easily see how this is a problem in another scenario.

So I guess my question is simple: Why isn't this working correctly when using a trigger?

**Edit:** To clarify, I have a 3rd sheet with some conditions/cells (i.e. conditions that influence which rows are to be copied) and changing them (like changing a different date) trigger the function.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

You are using an `onEdit` trigger to capture sheet changes. But `onEdit` triggers work only when the **user** changes the value of a cell. Referencing the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite):

> The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a **user** changes the value
> of any cell in a spreadsheet.

In your case, I think you are trying to execute this code when the `Form Responses` sheet is filled in with data by the form.

There are two kind of trigger functions that work with form submissions and they are both [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

One is a [google sheet event based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) and the other one a [form event based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1).

Your goal is to execute some code from the google sheets side, so it makes sense to use the first one.

### Modifications:

1. Change the name of the function from `onEdit` to a different name of your choice e.g. `myFormSubmitTrigger`.
2. Since the trigger is installable you need to "install" a `onFormSubmit` trigger for the `myFormSubmitTrigger` function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992718/how-to-get-onformsubmit-to-trigger-automatically) you can find some simple instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I do actually want (and do) want to trigger this when changing a value in a cell (more specifically, changing a cell that determines which cells to copy). And the code should work either way, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Markstar the question is who is going to change the value of the cell? a formula? a script? a filled in form? the user?

Comment: The user. I have a sheet with conditions and the plan was that whenever one condition is changed, the function is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is why doesn't your function work when the form makes changes to sheet Form Responses 1 then Marios has answered you question accept it and move on.  If your trying to run your function when a user is making edits to sheet Form Responses 1 using a simple trigger then a possible explanation for not getting all of the rows completely copied is that simple trigger must complete in 30 seconds.  If you continue to accept more data in Form 1 Responses then soon or later you will have problems but with this function it will be a lot later because it will run much faster than your code:

```
function updateDataRange() {
  const sss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const ssh=e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  const sr=2;
  const svs=ssh.getRange(sr,2,sh.getLastRow()-ssr+1,7).getValues();
  const dsh=e.source.getSheetByName('DataRange');
  dsh.clear();
  dsh.getRange(1,1,svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```

However, I would recommend that you never edit a form responses sheet.  I would consider using the onFormSubmit trigger to capture all of the data to a second sheet that is available to edit.  And it will have additional data automatically appended to it via `dsh.appendRow(e.values)`.  And so now you would no longer require an onEdit trigger because your data sheet is kept upto data with an onFormSubmit trigger and you may feel free to edit the  datasheet any time you wish.

If neither of these questions suffices then I would recommend that you be more clear about what you are asking.

Comment: The function does execute - it is just buggy, i.e. some rows are skipped and some rows are copied multiple times. On my test file, the script takes about 5 seconds. Furthermore, the trigger is from another sheet, so that should not influence the data.  I will edit my post above in order to make it clearer.

Comment: Please make it clearer and please be clear about what trigger you are using and what is being edited and what is the expected output.  We should be able to take you code and reproduce the same problem.  Read about [mcve]