# Changed to DriveApp still have same issue TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

Changed to DriveApp still have same challenges and error message

```
var docTemplate = "1nBZvKTMk5b82tiNvMqG3obmbY-lBIpodrIjvH-_sf7g";
var DocName = "SpringHillDisciplineReport";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = "kroper@lexrich5.org, lweaver@lexrich5.org, eddavis@lexrich5.org";
  var studentname = e.values[2];
  var studentgrade = e.values[6];
  var date = e.values[5];
  var reportername = e.values[3];
  var locationofincident = e.values[8];
  var reasonforthereferral = e.values[9];
  var presentactiontakenbyadministrator = e.values[13];
  var infractioncode = e.values [10];
  var additionalcomments = e.values[14];

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(DocName+' for '+ studentname)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyStudentName', studentname);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', date);
copyBody.replaceText('keyStudentGrade', studentgrade);
copyBody.replaceText('keyLocationofIncident', locationofincident);
copyBody.replaceText('keyReasonfortheReferral',reasonforthereferral);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPresentActionTakenbyAdministrator',presentactiontakenbyadministrator);
copyBody.replaceText('keyAdditionalComments', additionalcomments);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Discipline Referral Report";
var body = "Here is the Discipline Referral Report for " + studentname + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update DocsList to DriveApp in my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777164/how-to-update-docslist-to-driveapp-in-my-code)

Comment: var docTemplate = "1nBZvKTMk5b82tiNvMqG3obmbY-lBIpodrIjvH-_sf7g";
var DocName = "SpringHillDisciplineReport";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var email_address = "kroper@lexrich5.org, lweaver@lexrich5.org, eddavis@lexrich5.org";
var studentname = e.values[2]; THIS IS THE LINE WITH ERROR 
var studentgrade = e.values[6];
var date = e.values[5];
var reportername = e.values[3];
var locationofincident = e.values[8];
var reasonforthereferral = e.values[9];
var presentactiontakenbyadministrator = e.values[13];

Comment: It won't let me post entire code

Comment: Also it has been working for over a year and I didn't change anything all of a sudden this morning stopped working

Comment: it is not a duplicate of DocsList

Comment: you need to edit the original post and include all your code there instead of trying to put it in comments.

Comment: Ok I have fixed it to include the code I didn't change anything prior to it stopping to work today

Comment: Take a look at [Getting TypeError in onFormSubmit trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17984695/1677912)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Answer (score 2):

The [DocsList service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset), which was deprecated in 2014, has been sunset and no longer functions. Users relying on DocsList should switch to [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

The two places in your code where you use DocsList should be updated for use with DriveApp

**You cannot run this code from the code editor** as it requires a submission from a form to work properly. **You are receiving the error message that the value was undefined because there was no form submitted**. The real problem is with DocsList

Comment: Thanks I replaced that and am still getting the same error

Comment: did you read the last paragraph of my post? your code cannot be run from the code editor.you must submit a form to get it to run properly.

Comment: I did however I am not a programmer I had a form letter that was used for discipline that would merge with a google form and this script would run on form submit and it was working until yesterday when I started getting the error I just need some direction on what I can do to fix it at this point.

Comment: the only way to test it is by submitting a form. Can you submit a dummy form and see if that works?

Comment: Whew! glad to hear it. I thought you were going to have to invite me over to fix it.